# execCommand not working for xml file

Tags: javascript, dom, mozilla, gecko

I am using execCommand command to 'Hilite' selected text on the page which is rendered with gecko engine/gtkmozembed.

```
if ( !document.execCommand("HiliteColor", false, colour) ) {
                document.execCommand("BackColor", false, colour);
}
```

This is working fine with HTML pages. But i have some XML pages( books in xml format). execCommand is not working for those XML pages. It gives warning like

```
TypeError: document.execCommand is not a function
```

How can i make execCommand works on XML? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

XML has no visual representation layer by default. It is only a data container. Try transforming the XML documents into HTML documents using XSLT. Then any JavaScript will work perfectly.